# Create data set based on object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting data like below :

```
data.filter = {
    selectedFilterItems: [
        {
            name: "0-435",
            categoryId: "0_435",
            code: "price",
            totalItems: 1,
        },
        {
            name: "MULTI",
            categoryId: "7608",
            count: 633,
            code: "color",
            subcategories: [],
            totalItems: 1,
        },
        {
            name: "Pastel Tie Dye",
            categoryId: "566962",
            count: 1,
            code: "color",
            subcategories: [],
            totalItems: 1,
        },
    ],
    totalItems: 3,
};
```

I need to create a json like below, where type will be the "code" i get from above data (i.e data.filter)
& the value will be comma seperated for common code.

**Desired Output** :

```
filters: [
    {
      type: 'price',
      value: '0-435'
    }
]
```

exg for color there will be only one type = color & its value will be "MULTI,Pastel Tie Dye".

if only one distinct code is there in data.filter then only that data will be in filters.

Here is the code which i am trying

```
if(data.filter) {
const selectedFilterItems = data.filter.selectedFilterItems.reduce((property, attribute) => {
    if (property[attribute.code]) {
      property[attribute.code].value += `,${attribute.name}`;
    } else {
      property[attribute.code] = { type: attribute.code, value: attribute.name };
    }
    return property;
    }, {});
    filter_data = Object.values(selectedFilterItems);
  }
```

i need to add to the "filter_data" variable.

```
{
      type: 'category',
      value: '7608' //  where the value will be there "selectedFilterItems's any of the property's categoryId's value.
}
```

Comment: Should the `sorts` property be in the desired output? It's not part of the input

Comment: That's fine, its static.
i have removed from desired data.

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service, what have you tried already to accomplish this? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you taken a look at [arr.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)? If not, take a look at the examples with objects

Comment: Yes let me updated question, i am trying to make it work
may be i need to loop through the "selectedFilterItems"

Comment: Let me try the code.
Also any answers to this question are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to filter the data and extract it with `Object.values()`

```js
const data = { selectedFilterItems: [ { name: "0-435", categoryId: "0_435", code: "price", totalItems: 1, }, { name: "MULTI", categoryId: "7608", count: 633, code: "color", subcategories: [], totalItems: 1, }, { name: "Pastel Tie Dye", categoryId: "566962", count: 1, code: "color", subcategories: [], totalItems: 1, }, ], totalItems: 3, };

const groupByData = data.selectedFilterItems.reduce((acc, b) => {
  if (acc[b.code]) {
    acc[b.code].value += `,${b.name}`;
  } else {
    acc[b.code] = { type: b.code, value: b.name };
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

const output = Object.values(groupByData);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the value for "type" property should be the "code" 's value from the input.

Comment: @devhs, updated. I have some typo.

Comment: The "acc & b" used in above code are just random argument names right ?

Comment: @devhs, yes. it is up to you.

Comment: Also what is the use of the $ in acc[b.code].value += `,${b.name}`; ?

Comment: @devhs, if the `acc[b.code]` exist in the `acc` , you don't need to reassign a new object for it and you just want to append the value with name properties. and when you append the value, you want to add `,` in between.

Comment: Very helpful, thankyou very much.
let me try it with code to see it works.

Comment: There will be no chance of any error right in this ?

Comment: @devhs, if `code` and `name` always exist in your data, there should be no error.

Comment: I need to add
{type: 'category',value: 'Tops'} this value to the "output"
where the value will be there "selectedFilterItems's  any of the property's categoryId's value.

Comment: Can you please advice me on that ?

Comment: @devhs ,  What if the `categoryId` is duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = {};

data.filter = {
    selectedFilterItems: [
        {
            name: "0-435",
            categoryId: "0_435",
            code: "price",
            totalItems: 1,
        },
        {
            name: "MULTI",
            categoryId: "7608",
            count: 633,
            code: "color",
            subcategories: [],
            totalItems: 1,
        },
        {
            name: "Pastel Tie Dye",
            categoryId: "566962",
            count: 1,
            code: "color",
            subcategories: [],
            totalItems: 1,
        },
    ],
    totalItems: 3,
};

let filters = [];
let codes = []

data.filter.selectedFilterItems.forEach((elem)=>codes.push(elem.code));  //store all codes in an array

codes = [...new Set(codes)]   //create a set of codes which will only contain unique entities

codes.forEach(code=>{                              //Iterate over the codes
  let obj = {}, val="";
  data.filter.selectedFilterItems.forEach(elem=>{  //Iterate over each selectedFilterItems object
    if(elem.code === code){
      val += elem.name + ",";                  // Add the name to val if the code matches
    }
  })
  val = val.substring(0, val.length-1);  //Remove last char that will be comma
  obj["type"] = code;
  obj["value"] = val;
  filters.push(obj)  
})

console.log(filters)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer & explanation